# WaveOut versus WaveOutEvent

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm using `NAudio` with

```
WaveOutEvent Klangwiedergabegeraet;

private void Play(string Dateiname)
{
    Klangwiedergabegeraet = new WaveOutEvent();
    Klangwiedergabegeraet.DeviceNumber = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    ISampleProvider StueckchenHalter = null;
    StueckchenHalter = CreateInputStreamS(Dateiname);
    Klangwiedergabegeraet.Init(new SampleToWaveProvider(StueckchenHalter));  
    Klangwiedergabegeraet.Play();
}

private void Cancel()
{
    if (Klangwiedergabegeraet != null)
    {
        Klangwiedergabegeraet.Stop();
        Klangwiedergabegeraet.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When running `Cancel()`, it won't stop. When I used

```
WaveOut Klangwiedergabegeraet;

private void Play(string Dateiname)
{
    Klangwiedergabegeraet = new WaveOut();
    ...
}

private void Cancel()
{
    if (Klangwiedergabegeraet != null)
    {
        Klangwiedergabegeraet.Stop();
        Klangwiedergabegeraet.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It worked. Why is this and what to change?

**P.S** I am using `WaveOutEvent` instead of `WaveOut` because `WaveOut` does not have the property `DeviceNumber`.

Comment: WaveOutEvent is more sensitive to crappy audio drivers.  WaveOut *does* have a DeviceNumber property so maybe you should first update your version of NAudio.

Comment: *`Klangwiedergabegeraet`* - seriously? :/ Sounds like one of the worst german variable names I've ever read... and as a more serious suggestion, using the default names for UI elements such as `comboBox1` is a bad idea.

Comment: It's an object, no variable. And I like `StueckchenHalter` even more - how does that make you feel?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Jetzt sehe ich erst, daß du Deutscher bist. Da es hier keine PN-Funktion gibt antworte ich eben hier auf deutsch. Ja, ich verwende gerne deutsche Objektnamen, sogar im Originalcode mit ä und ß.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running on a non-GUI thread, then `WaveOutEvent` is the recommended way to do things, not `WaveOut` as that will choose function callbacks which can be unreliable on some soundcards. Also, `WaveOut` does have a `DeviceNumber` property.

Comment: According to Intellisense, it doesn't. For some reason without changing anything I am aware of, WaveOutEvent is working now.

Comment: `WaveOutEvent` has a `DeviceNumber` property as well. This question is from 2012, so maybe things have change since.